# Why do we have duplicated "mark as duplicate" when voting / flagging questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I was wondering when marking / flagging a question as a duplicate, I see two identical options: "*A duplicated "mark as duplicate"* "

**One in the first page:**

[image]

**Another under "Should be closed" page:**

[image]

I assume the one under "Should be closed" should be removed. **Can we remove it? And should we?**

Comment: "question usually do not get closed"?, why?, they get closed as any other question, related  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/flag-usability-change-it-doesnt-belong-here-to-it-should-be-closed, furthermore >3K is enough to close question

Comment: *since "marked as duplicate" question usually do not get closed (Needs +10k user privilege)* - ***??***

Comment: @nicael I meant to say it does not get deleted immidiately and/or removed from the site. I will edit and remove that sorry

Answer (score 0):

You must have mistaken "closed" with "deleted", per your edited-out sentence - *"since "marked as duplicate" question usually do not get closed (Needs +10k user privilege)"*.

"Should be closed" is exactly what the dialog tells you, and it's not "Should be *deleted*". "Duplicate" is just one of the "reasons for closing a question" <sup>1</sup>. Deletion is a completely different process. A post can be deleted but not closed, and closed but not deleted, or both closed and deleted.

---

Some faq:

- <sup>1</sup> [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

---

A related question: [New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196583/new-flagging-dialog-has-a-duplicate-for-duplicate)

Comment: Hi nic and thanks for answeing. Yes I think I got a little bit confused, however that was just for my assumption on what really happens after the flagging process. My actual question though is why do we have two duplicated "mark as duplicate" and should we remove one?