# For close vote privilege users, the Duplicate option repeats

Tags: bug, close-reasons

For people with Close Vote privilege, when choose flag, the option to mark duplicate repeats 2 times and both points to same window.

#### First one is in the main menu.

[image]

#### The second one is in the *Should be closed menu*

[image]

#### And both points to

[image]

Comment: I don't see the issue. It are two dialogs, what should be changed according to you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman To repro, instead of close, choose flag. Then you can see a _dupe_ option there. Choose _should be closed_ and it repeats there

Comment: Because the first is the flag dialog and you can click through to the close dialog. Both have the duplicate option.

Comment: yes. I think it is a bug because both points to same option (3rd image). So one option is necessary.

Comment: the flag->dupe also points to flag->close->dupe

Comment: Because we want to encourage to flag as duplicate.

Comment: agreed. but I would like to know is this is the real purpose behind it. Usually if someone achieve the CV privilege, then the Flag dupe option should be removed. right ?

Comment: You could remove all options that lead to closure, but then users acquiring the privilege might be too used to go to the flag dialog that they don't see the close option.

Comment: I think I should make it clear. I mean the dupe option in the first image should be removed. because it will not treated as a flag when casted by CV privilege user. it will be treated as a CV. So, the dupe option should appear in the Close option

Comment: or a more recent dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283616/why-do-we-have-duplicated-mark-as-duplicate-when-voting-flagging-questions/283618#283618

Comment: The title is too different than my search terms.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicates of duplicate of duplicate. I will delete this now